# While getting notification, app is crashing

Tags: android

Device is registering but problem in getting notification, I tried in many ways but not succeeded. please anyone help me on this. 
    Below is my GCMIntentService.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package in.oneindia.android.clickin;

import static in.oneindia.android.clickin.utils.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;

import in.oneindia.android.clickin.LeftAndRightActivity;
import in.oneindia.android.clickin.MailActivity;
import in.oneindia.android.clickin.R;
import in.oneindia.android.clickin.HomeActivity;
import in.oneindia.android.clickin.SplashScreenActivity;
import in.oneindia.android.clickin.utils.CommonUtilities;
import in.oneindia.android.clickin.utils.ServerUtilities;
import in.oneindia.android.clickin.utils.SharedPrefUtils;
import in.oneindia.android.clickin.utils.Util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
/**
 * IntentService responsible for handling GCM messages.
 */
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() 
    {
        super(CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Util.logv(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered));
        ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);

        String strId = registrationId;
        //Log.v("","CHECKING GCM WORKING OR NOT:::::::"+strId);

        if (strId != null) {
            SharedPrefUtils.setPushID(context, strId);
            //this.saveRegistrationIdAndSendToServer(strId);
        }
    }

    public String  saveRegistrationIdAndSendToServer(String registrationId)
    {
        String strRegistrationId=null;
        Util.logv("C2DM", "Sending registration ID to my application server");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://rss.oneindia.in/apps/registerId.php?action="+registrationId);
        try
        {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                strRegistrationId= line;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strRegistrationId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Util.logv(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
        } else {
            // This callback results from the call to unregister made on
            // ServerUtilities when the registration to the server failed.
            Util.logv(TAG, "Ignoring unregister callback");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Util.logv(TAG, "Received message");

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {          
            String myTitle = intent.getStringExtra("classifiedTitle");
            String myPostID = intent.getStringExtra("postID");
            String myImage = intent.getStringExtra("classifiedImage");
            //String csFlashNews = intent.getStringExtra("flash_news");
            //String csShowAd = intent.getStringExtra("show_ad");
            //String csFlashContent = intent.getStringExtra("flash_content");

            Util.logv(TAG, "TITLE : "+myTitle);
            Util.logv("MyPOSTID", "POST ID : "+myPostID);

            String s=myTitle.toString();
            parse_json_add(s);
            displayMessage(context, myTitle);
            // notifies user
            generateNotification(context, myTitle, myPostID, myImage);
        }        
    }

    private void parse_json_add(String text) {
        if (text!= null) 
        { 
            try {
                JSONObject temp=new JSONObject(text);
                String value=temp.get("state").toString();    
                Log.v(TAG, value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Util.logv(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        String entryID = null;
        String URL = null;
        /*String flashNews = null;
        String showAd = null;
        String flashContent = null;*/
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message, entryID, URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Util.logv(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Util.logv(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    public static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String EntryID, String src) {

        //String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        String title = "Click.in";

        //String URL = "http://tamil.oneindia.in/img/2014/05/25-kejriwal113434-600.jpg";
        Bitmap largeIcon = getBitmapFromUrl(src);
        if(largeIcon == null)
        {
            largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.clickinicon512x512);
        }
        try
        {
            double ArticleEntryID = 0;
            int csbooleanFlashNews = 0;
            int csbooleanShowAd = 0;
            if(EntryID != null && !EntryID.equals(""))
            {
                ArticleEntryID = Double.parseDouble(EntryID);
            }
            /*if(strBooleanFlashNews != null && !strBooleanFlashNews.equals(""))
            {
                csbooleanFlashNews = Integer.parseInt(strBooleanFlashNews);
            }
            if(strBooleanShowAd != null && !strBooleanShowAd.equals(""))
            {
                csbooleanShowAd = Integer.parseInt(strBooleanShowAd);
            }*/
            Intent  notificationIntent;
            if(ArticleEntryID == 0)
            {
                notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("checkingpush", "PUSH");
                /*notificationIntent.putExtra("showad", csbooleanShowAd);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("flashnews", csbooleanFlashNews);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("flashnewscontent", csFlashContent);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("selectedposition", 0);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("channelid", 0);*/
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            }
            else
            {   
                notificationIntent = new Intent(context, LeftAndRightActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("pushdata", EntryID);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("title", csbooleanShowAd);
                //notificationIntent.putExtra("flashnews", csbooleanFlashNews);
                notificationIntent.putExtra("checkingpush", "PUSH");
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            }
            /*// set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);*/
            PendingIntent intent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            int id = sp.getInt("notifid", -1);
            id++;

            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            {
                // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.notification_layout_normal);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clickinicon512x512)
                .setTicker(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(intent)
                .setContent(remoteViews);

                //remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_imageview, largeIcon);
                //remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text_title, message);
                //remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_title_imageview, buildUpdate(context, message, SharedPrefUtils.getLanguage(context)));
                Notification n = builder.build();
                n.contentView = remoteViews;
                n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationmanager.notify(id, n);
            }else
            {
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                        in.oneindia.android.clickin.R.layout.notification_layout_expandable);
                remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_imageview, largeIcon);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text_title, message);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text_appname, title);

                builder.setContentIntent(intent)
                .setTicker(message)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(largeIcon, 100, 100, false))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clickinicon512x512);
                //.setAutoCancel(true);

                Notification n = builder.build();

                /*if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                {
                    n.bigContentView = remoteViews;
                }*/
                n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                nm.notify(id, n);


            }

            if ( id > 10){ // Overwrite notification 10 notification is very long list
                sp.edit().remove("notifid").commit(); //async
            } else {
                sp.edit().putInt("notifid",id).commit();
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src)
    {
        URL url = null;
        InputStream input = null;

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(src);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        Bitmap  myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    }

    public static Bitmap buildUpdate(Context context, String txt, String lang) 
    {

        int bmapwidth = 320;
        int bmapheight = 60;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int csWidth = dm.widthPixels;

        float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float txtsize = 14;
        float csLineSpaceAdd = 1f;
        float csLineSpaceMul = 1f;
        if(csWidth <=240)
        {
            bmapwidth = 220;
            bmapheight = 55;
        }else if(csWidth > 240 && csWidth <= 320)
        {
            bmapwidth = 280;
            bmapheight = 60;
        }else if(csWidth > 320 && csWidth <= 600) 
        {
            bmapwidth = 350;
        }else if (csWidth > 600) {
            bmapwidth = 400;
        }

        String language = lang;
        if (language.equals("6"))
        {
            if(density <= 0.75)
            {
                txtsize = 20;
            }
            else if(density > 0.75 && density <= 1)
            {
                txtsize = 17;
            }
            else if(density > 1 && density < 2)
            {
                txtsize=14;
            }
            else if(density >= 2)
            {
                txtsize=13;
            }
        }else if (language.equals("7"))
        {
            if(density <= 0.75)
            {
                txtsize = 18;
            }
            else if(density > 0.75 && density < 2)
            {
                txtsize=15;
            }
            else if(density >= 2)
            {
                txtsize=13;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(density <= 0.75)
            {
                txtsize = 17;
            }
            else if(density > 0.75 && density < 2)
            {
                txtsize=14;
            }
            else if(density >= 2)
            {
                txtsize=13;
            }
        }
        String title_txt = txt;

        Typeface langFont = null;
        Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmapwidth, bmapheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Log.v("languageSelected : ", language);
        Log.v("Title : ", ""+txt);
        if (language.equals("2")) {
            langFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/hindi.ttf");
            csLineSpaceAdd = -1.8f;
            csLineSpaceMul = 0.8f;
        }else if (language.equals("3")) {
            langFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/kannada.ttf");
            csLineSpaceAdd = -0.8f;
        }else if (language.equals("4")) {
            langFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/telugu.ttf");
            csLineSpaceAdd = -0.8f;
        }else if (language.equals("5")) {
            langFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/malayalam.ttf");
            csLineSpaceAdd = -0.7f;
        }else if (language.equals("6")) {
            //title_txt = TamilUtil.convertToTamil(TamilUtil.BAMINI, txt, context);
            langFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Bamini.ttf");
        }else if (language.equals("7")) {
            langFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/lohit_gu.ttf");
            csLineSpaceAdd = 0.5f;
        }


        //Log.v("typeface : ", ""+langFont);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setSubpixelText(true);
        paint.setTypeface(langFont);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        TextView csText=new TextView(context);
        csText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        csText.setTypeface(langFont);
        csText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        csText.setText(title_txt);
        csText.setTextSize(txtsize);
        csText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        csText.setLines(2);
        csText.setLineSpacing(csLineSpaceAdd, csLineSpaceMul);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bmapwidth, bmapheight);
        csText.setLayoutParams(lp);
        csText.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        csText.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(myCanvas.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(myCanvas.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        csText.layout(0, 0, csText.getMeasuredWidth(), csText.getMeasuredHeight());
        myCanvas.drawBitmap(csText.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, paint);
        csText.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);


        return myBitmap;
    }

    public static void cancelAllNotification(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

}
```

Below are permissions which I gave in Manifest.xml. Please help me on this

```
<permission
        android:name="in.oneindia.android.clickin.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="in.oneindia.android.clickin.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

 <service android:name="in.oneindia.android.clickin.GCMIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
    enter code here
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="in.oneindia.android.clickin" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: where is your logcat???

Comment: are you getting `Util.logv(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);` in logcat?

Comment: I got pushID for perticular device. and while trying to push notification using thai pushID I;m getting app crash.

Comment: @MaheshSiddalingam: post crash log with question

Comment: I'm not able to log that crash in my device

Comment: restart eclipse to log to get working...

Comment: no there is a `perspective` in your IDE called `LogCat` where these logs are listed, please post those red colored logs when you see a `crash`